# Which is easier for human perception: type of variable before or after its name?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, educational-psychology, reading, language-processing

In some programming languages type of variable goes before it's name.
In another - name goes first and then type.
For example if I declare string:
`String s = "some string"`
Or
`val s: String = "some string"`
Which version loads brain less and allow easier think about problem ?

Comment: I have no idea if this question is more appropriate for here or cs.stackexchange. Regardless, I'm pretty sure the answer is that we don't know. Heck, we just started to measure [if curly braces are a good idea](http://neverworkintheory.org/2014/01/29/stefik-siebert-syntax.html) (they aren't).

Comment: I think this may also depend on the [regular] language [used to communicate in everyday life]. For example, English places its adjectives before the subject (type-object, e.g. 'wooden chair'), while in French its the reverse ('chaise en bois')

Comment: @AliceD But type isn't adjective, it's a noun that describes name. We say 'Lucky is a dog', i.e. <name> is a <type>, so type comes after name in English. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Anyway, my point really was if you've done some research yourself so to scope the question.

Comment: This is an interesting question, although I doubt it has been researched. If we follow the natural language analogy, then "s is a string variable" is the most natural expression, so formally something like "s: String [var]" but most programming languages don't look like that. I think Perl is the only language that tried to have "naturally sounding" versions of some language constructs, but not related to typing, as far as I remember. On the other hand you could read the fist construct as "[the] String s is ...". So I guess it's opinion based without a usability study.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer (if this has been researched) on the PPIG mailing list http://www.ppig.org/about